# Can date filters be used on the riskDetections endpoint in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to pull just the most recent detections from the riskDetections endpoint for Microsoft Graph API. Here's an example query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityProtection/riskDetections?filter=detectedDateTime eq 2020-09-15
```

I can run this query successfully in the Graph Explorer site, but it's returning results dating back to 2020-06-25.

If a filter is not valid for a given endpoint, does it simply ignore the filter rather than producing an error?

Edit: I figured out my problem. I forgot the $ in front of filter. When correctly formatted, the endpoint rejects my query with an error. However, it seems I can accomplish essentially the same thing by using orderby.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityProtection/riskDetections?$orderby=detectedDateTime desc
```

I'll just stop pulling results once I hit my desired recent date cutoff, and do local data filtering to get exactly what I want.

However, I'd still appreciate if someone could figure out how to make date filters work with this endpoint.

Comment: Please check the below query Its needs to be in full-time formate `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityProtection/riskDetections?filter=detectedDateTime eq 2020-08-14T12:55:05.6048702Z`

Comment: That worked! Please put that as an Answer so I can mark my question Answered.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below query Its needs to be in full-time formate `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityProtection/riskDetections?filter=detectedDateTime eq 2020-08-14T12:55:05.6048702Z`

[image]